# I do not visualize the changes I make in sqlplus in SQL Developer in an oracle 12c database, which I am raising with docker

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, pluggable-database

Good afternoon, I am working with docker and an oracle 12c database, the official image found in the docker hub, the question is that I am testing creating a user from the SQL Plus, and when I am going to verify in the SQL developer, Note that the changes executed with the SQL Plus are not displayed in the SQL Developer, even having made the respective console commit (as shown in the image)

Creation of the user, commit and the current user of the session:

[image]

Then checking in the SQL Developer:

[image]

The configuration of the SQL Developer, with the port and ip of the host (not of the container) and the user of the session:

[image]

What can I need to configure? I've been looking for a solution for hours and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

container should be set before creating a user for a pluggable DB :

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = orclpdb1;
```

and display whether connected to that container :

```
SQL> SHOW CON_NAME

CON_NAME
------------------------------
ORCLPDB1
```

and finally create concerned *user* :

```
SQL> CREATE USER cesar IDENTIFIED BY prueba123 [CONTAINER=CURRENT];
```

*square bracketed part is optional*

Comment: I will test it as soon as I can connect remotely

Comment: It worked, thank very much. Could you send me a link or information about why is it necessary to do this?

Comment: you're welcome @CesarJusto . [Pluggable DBs](https://logicalread.com/2015/05/29/oracle-pluggable-databases-mc05/#.XgoV7kczZPY) can be plugged into and unplugged from a Container DB. They're individual DBs held together by CDBs.